# ASP.NET WebApi form-urlencoded string deserialize

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I develop service with WebApi and Client which send to this service gzipped data by POST method (to save bandwidth). Both of them over my control. On server I receive compressed data, decompress It and have string such as:

```
section[0][caption]=Foo&
section[0][address]=175896&
section[0][counters][]=2&
section[0][counters][]=2&
section[0][errors][]=ERR_NOT_AVAILABLE&
errors=true&
trmtimestamp=1346931864358
```

ie simple www-form-urlencoded string.

Does ASP.NET MVC4 WebApi have some method to bind or deserialize this string to my Model?

```cs
public class Snapshot
{
    public List<SectionState> sections { get; set; }
    public bool errors { get; set; }
    public double date { get; set; }
    public double trmtimestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is `SectionState` some sort of key/value pair?

Comment: @Chris no, It's simple class `{ string caption, int address, int[] counters, string[] errors }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use the following code to parse the string:

```
new System.Net.Http.Formatting.FormDataCollection(query).ReadAs<Snapshot>();
```

The ReadAs is extension method defined under System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormDataCollectionExtensions.

Comment: You're a Hero Hongye Sun!

Comment: Is there a way of doing this in .NET Core 3.1?  The FormDataCollection object seems to be missing.